# Как сохранить дерево в файл, а после его загрузить?

Tags: c, файлы, указатели, дерево

Как сохранить АВЛ-дерево, обладающее сл. структурой:

```
struct avlleaf { // структура для представления узлов дерева
    char key[256];                                // Ключ
    unsigned long long int llupar;                // Числовой параметр
    long long int height;                         // Высота
    struct avlleaf* left;                        // Левый ребенок
    struct avlleaf* right;                       // Правый ребенок
};
```

в файл и затем загрузить его из файла

Comment: Если дерево нормально сбалансировано: пишем корень, прямо как есть. далее обходим дерево и пишем все проходимые узлы в направлении движения вниз. всегда придерживаемся одного правила движения, например сначала идем налево, по возвращении - направо. все указатели в файле особого смысла не имеют. Но по потому, что они не NULL при чтении можно будет понять, что в данной точке мы более не углублялись. А зная это мы можем прочитать блоки в точно таком порядке как писали. При чтении меняем все указатели на новые

Comment: @Mike: А как это связано с тем, сбалансировано дерево или нет?

Comment: @AnT Хм. никак :) У меня сначала была другая идея, там предполагалось писать все возможные листья (даже не существующие), заранее их пронумеровав. Не хотелось много "дыр" в файле. А потом подумал, что все проще и уже написал все остальное :)

Comment: @Mike А как писать в файл

Comment: http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/write-rtlwrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, я бы писал рекурсивно. Функция записи узла примерно такая (псевдокод!)

```
void write(avlleaf*a)
{
    // Запись key, llupar, height
    // Если есть левый - пишем 1 и write(a->left), если нет - 0
    // Если есть правый - пишем 1 и write(a->right), если нет - 0
}
```

И записываю, передавая указатель на корень.

Читать - наоборот:

```
avlleaf* read()
{
    // Создаю новый avlleaf
    // Читаю в него key, llupar, height
    // Читаю флаг. Если 1 - a->left = read(), если 0 - иду дальше
    // Читаю флаг. Если 1 - a->right = read(), если 0 - иду дальше
    // Возвращаю указатель на созданный avlleaf
}
```

Примерно так...

Comment: Спасибо, щас опробуем